# The ViewData item that has the key is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, ienumerable

This is my model class:

```
public class EstimateModel:estimate
{
    public string EstimateNo { get; set; }

    //public SelectList Customer { get; set; }
    //[DisplayName("Customer ID :")]
    public int CustID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Customer Name :")]
    public string CustFname { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Company Name :")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Total:")]
    public decimal total { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Tax1 :")]
    public decimal tax1 { get; set; }

    public decimal tax2 { get; set; }

    public decimal tax3 { get; set; }

    public decimal subtot { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Discount :")]
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("GrandTotal:")]
    public decimal grandtotal { get; set; }

    public List<estimate> estimates { get; set; }

    public EstimateModel()
    {
        estimates = new List<estimate>();
    }
}
```

This is my controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(EstimateModel employee)
    {
        //employee.Customer= new SelectList("CustID","CustFName");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        //for (int i = 0; i < employee.estimates.Count; i++)
        //{

        //    total = total + employee.estimates[i].Amount;

        //} ViewBag.Message = total;
        //Skill abc = new Skill();

               var sys = db.EstimateMasters.Create();
               // var user = db.Adils.Create();
               sys.EstimateNo = employee.EstimateNo;

       for(int i=0 ;i<employee.estimates.Count;i++)
       {
           sys.EstimateNo = employee.EstimateNo;
           sys.CustID = employee.CustID;
               sys.ProductName =  employee.estimates[i].ProductName;
               sys.Quantity = employee.estimates[i].Quantity;
               sys.Price = employee.estimates[i].Price;
               sys.Amount = employee.estimates[i].Amount;
               sys.Total=employee.total;
           sys.Tax1=employee.tax1;
           sys.Tax2 = employee.tax2;
           sys.Tax3 = employee.tax3;
           sys.Discount = employee.Discount;
           sys.SubTotal = employee.subtot;
           sys.GrandTotal = employee.grandtotal;

               db.EstimateMasters.Add(sys);
               db.SaveChanges();
       }
```

This is my view code:

```
        <div> @Html.LabelFor(m =>m.CustID)
    @Html.DropDownList("CustID", "---Select---")

        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustFname)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m =>m.CustFname)
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.CompanyName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m =>m.CompanyName)
    </div>
```

I am getting this error on `DropDownList`: `The ViewData item that has the key 'CustID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you show us the first top line of your view?

Comment: @model isparx.Models.EstimateModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</p>

Comment: You're missing some chunks of code but the source of your error is clear enough: you are trying to instantiate the `DropDownList` using and integer property, but the helper needs an enumerable collection of `SelectedListItem`. Basically, you need all the `CustID`s to be in a list.

Comment: Think about this for a moment. `CustID` is an `int`. You're asking the system to display a drop down list - but how is it meant to know what options should appear in that list? Maybe switch to a different overload of `DropDownList` where, in addition to telling it which field this is for, you also provide an explicit list of items it should display.

Comment: Please post also your `GET` controller. Your (current) problem is in the initialization phase of the view, not in the post result.

Comment: // GET: /Estimate/
        public ActionResult Create()
        {

            //IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CustID = new SelectList("CustID","CustID");
            //ViewBag.CustID = CustID;


            ViewBag.CustID = new SelectList(db.CustomerMasters, "CustID", "CustID");
            var e = new EstimateModel();
            e.estimates.Insert(0, new estimate());
            return View(e);
        }

Comment: Use `@Html.DropDownList(ViewBag.CustID", "---Select---")`. The Razor engine was trying to load the `CustID` property in your Model, but you're passing the list trough the `ViewBag`. As a side note, you should never add to the `ViewBag` properties with the same name as on of the Model's properties.

Comment: i changed the name of viewbag property but then again got error... is there any other method of dropdownlist...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass list to dropdown but here you are passing CustID and that is Integer. This is causing error.

Try following code:

1) Create a list with your items.

```
@{
List<SelectListItem> CustIDlistItems= new List<SelectListItem>();
CustIDlistItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
      Text = "text1",
      Value = "value1"
    });
CustIDlistItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "text2",
        Value = "value2",
        Selected = true
    });
CustIDlistItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "text3",
        Value = "value3"
    });
}
```

2) Pass newly created list to view with list as a parameter.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Yourproperty, CustIDlistItems, "-- Select Status --")
```

Hope this will help you..!

EDIT :

You can utilize following example for creating dynamic list from database.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetTrainingSubjectsList(int selectedValue)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> TrainingSubjectsList = new List<SelectListItem>();

            TrainingSubjectsList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Selected = true, Text = "Select Subject", Value = "" });
            var TrainingSubjects = (from subjects in _context.TrainingDetails.Where(c => c.IsDeleted == false)
                                    select subjects).ToList();

            foreach (TrainingDetail TrainingDetail in TrainingSubjects)
            {
                SelectListItem Item = new SelectListItem();

                Item.Text = TrainingDetail.Title;
                Item.Value = TrainingDetail.TrainingDetailId.ToString();

                if (selectedValue == TrainingDetail.TrainingDetailId)
                {
                    Item.Selected = true;
                }

                TrainingSubjectsList.Add(Item);
            }

            return TrainingSubjectsList;
        }
```

Comment: how can i take dynamic list .. because i have to fetch CustID from database.. this is static list ...

Comment: @Pratik : I have added example in Edit. You can utilize given example to generate dynamic list.

Comment: my error was removed... i had given redirection link to another page.. thank you for dynamic list example .. it will help me...

Comment: Where are you getting the error. I can not see isdetected anywhere in code.

Comment: in linq condition where c => IsDetected == false

Comment: Oh..That is "isdeleted" and not "isdetected" in linq condition. You can not find it as it is a property of my database. :) You can simply ignore the where condition from that linq condition..!!

Comment: and i have to write in get method?