# DropDown Population Error in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.PlayerId = new SelectList(db.Players, "Id", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

This is in the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PlayerId, "PlayerId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("PlayerId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PlayerId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I submit the form, it gives me the below error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ViewData item that has the key 'PlayerId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.'

I googled a lot but were not able to find the solution. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Generally you should use a ViewModel.

Comment: This code is confusing... you are putting PlayerId in view bag and pass it to your view, but in your view you are using a model, where is this model coming from? The better approach would be not to use ViewBag and just pass your model to the view.

Comment: @Abdul Raheem Ghani Have you checked my answer? It should have helped you and solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Write your `@Html.DropDownList` as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("PlayerId", ViewBag.PlayerId as SelectList,"Select Player", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Now it will work!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `SelectList` into dropdown but actually the model binder is confused between `PlayerId` as viewmodel property and `PlayerId` as `ViewBag` property, hence causing the error.

Better to create a viewmodel property which will store option list with different name:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }

    // other properties

    // option list here
    public List<SelectListItem> PlayerList { get; set; }
}
```

Then add the option lists from database into controller action:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new ViewModel();
    model.PlayerList = db.Players.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id }).ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

And use strongly-typed helper to bind it afterwards:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PlayerId, Model.PlayerList, "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Related issue:

[The ViewData item that has the key is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371763/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-of-type)